# Segmentation fault when initializing a std::vector<double>

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, stdvector

What are the possible causes of a segmentation fault at the following line?

```
std::vector<double> d(8);
```

Comment: A previous heap corruption

Comment: valgrind would be an option

Comment: What happens if you simply allocate the vector, without specifying the size?  Not that it would fix the problem, but might provide a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the possible causes of a segmentation fault at the following line?

The line itself is exceedingly unlikely to cause a segmentation fault. The only way that could happen is if you've exhausted stack. Do `(gdb) x/i $pc`. Is the crashing instruction a `PUSH` or a `CALL`? If so, stack exhaustion is probably the cause.

If the code is compiled with optimization, and the crashing instruction is `MOVDQA` or similar, then stack mis-alignment is likely to blame: some code in the stack is not aligning stack on 16-byte boundary, as required by the current ABI. Are you linking in some really old archive libraries? Are you building some code with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` or `1`? Bad idea!

If (much more likely) the crash doesn't *really* happen at that line, but rather in some code called *from* that line, and especially if the called code  is inside `malloc`, then previous heap corruption is most likely the cause.

To find it, use Valgrind or Address Sanitizer.

Comment: As @Dani immediately pointed out, the problem was a previous heap corruption.